# How to pull image to the left on twitter bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap 2.3 and am having some trouble pulling an image to the left. I need to create a comment box for my pictures (done) and lazy load the image (done). The problem is that I want the picture to be left-aligned related to the comment box. Instead, it's on the top. I am using Twitter's bootstrap modal for that.

Here's a demo of the code:

http://pastebin.com/hjh3pqyN (SO didn't format it correctly)

Here's the result:

[image]

I'd like to have the green selection on the left and the red one on the right, like this:

```
|-------------|
| WINDOW      |
| |-----|---| |
| |Green|Red| |
| |-----|---| |
|-------------|
```

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: set `display:inline-block`

Comment: @PranavCBalan thank you, and where would that be, at the modal? I'm really rookie when it comes to CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rather use built-in features than applying custom CSS to the elements:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span6">
   <!-- left goes here -->
  </div>
  <div class="span6">
   <!-- right goes here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Inside e.g left container, you can apply pull-left or pull-right class to the `<img>` to make it algined.

Comment: Thank you, your solution worked. The only problem is that the modal is small, the elements used to create the comments span (right) are all messed. Any ideas on how to solve that?

Comment: You should check the <form> width and <fieldset> width as well if you use it. I bet that you have spanX inside (eg. on the inputs or textareas), so you should inside right container add <div class="row-fluid"> <!-- forms and other things inside right container --> </div> to solve problems.

Comment: Thanks, I found an answer on that matter here!